# SyntaxHighlighter word wrap?

Tags: html, css, syntax-highlighting

I used syntaxhighlighter in my front web page to highlight code. But I came across a question that the word in the code isn't wrapped when the code length is longer than the length of the `<div>`.
[image]

then I googled it. And found a way mentioned below:

```
pre,code{ 
white-space:pre-wrap;/*css-3*/ 
white-space:-moz-pre-wrap;/*Mozilla,since1999*/ 
white-space:-pre-wrap;/*Opera4-6*/ 
white-space:-o-pre-wrap;/*Opera7*/ 
word-wrap:break-word;/*InternetExplorer5.5+*/　　
}
```

However, a new problem appeared, the line number is not corresponding to the actual code line：
[image]

My question is:

- **How can I avoid the code overflows while keep the code line be corresponding to the actual original code line?**

Comment: I explained the solution of the problem in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61882374/how-to-add-word-wrap-propery-to-syntaxhighlighter-evolved-v-3x

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CodeMirror](https://codemirror.net/) editor. It has a lot of feature support including word wrap and read-only like the Sublime Text Editor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it does correspond the **original** code lines. Because of the wrapping you are getting messed up with the numbering. Try wrapping the code with JavaScript - add new line symbol `\n` and and caret returning symbol `\r` (depends on your programming environment and its settings) and see if it helps.

Answer (score -2):

You have to make some changes to the JavaScript, too.

It's explained at the bottom of the comment section here, including a demonstration in jsfiddle: https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/issue/182/version-3-making-code-wrap

Comment: This leads to a 404. It's always better to answer the question directly on StackOverflow.